# Changing Auto Suggest behavior for <datalist> tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to modify the `<datalist>` tag to display every `<option>` value with the letter "A" in it. Or display all values that share a common word in them. This would be in Chrome. I know that Chrome and IE only display the `<option>` that start with what is typed in, but is there any way to modify this behavior in Chrome to allow the `<datalist>` to search for any letter/word and display all of the values that have that letter/word in it?

```
<input type = "text" id = "typeOfThings" list = "thatOneList"/>
<datalist id = "thatOneList">
<option>a pear</option>
<option>ab pear</option>
<option>b apple</option>
<option>c apple</option>
</datalist>
```

Basically if I type in Pear is there a way to display both "a pear" and "ab pear".

If not that's cool, I will just reword it, but there has to be some way to modify this with JavaScript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: with JQuery UI, i have found a fiddle working (I'm not the author) : http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/LUgcL/

Comment: As a simplistic workaround that doesn't require JavaScript, you can use the options' `value` attributes. `<option value="pear">a pear</option>` shows when the user types a "p".